# How to work around one value of (many) JSON key-value pairs that has an unescaped double quote for inches?

Tags: java, json, escaping, gson, double-quotes

I've tried the Simple JSON library and now I've turned to GSON but I'm getting a MalformedJSONException on a server's response string (of which I have no control over due to a fussy client *sigh*).

Have some code:

```
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

                if (result != null){

                    StringReader reader = new StringReader(result);
                    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);
                    jsonReader.setLenient(true);

                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonObject jsonOjb = (JsonObject)parser.parse(jsonReader);

                    .
                    .
                    .

               }

    }
```

The code will fail at `parser.parse(jsonReader)` and I'm pretty sure one of the reasons is due to this key-value in my response:

```
"itemdesc": Universal 7 " Boiling Ringplate (1800W),
```

I realise the value has no quotes around it, I'm hoping `jsonReader.setLenient(true)` will take care of that. But I've done some Googling on unescaped double quotes characters and Google seems to only tell me about instances when *correctly* escaped quotes \" get MalformedJSONExceptions. My problem is more the opposite!

So, I guess, my question is: is there a way for me to read my response one key-value pair at a time using GSON so that, if I run into an instance of an unescaped double quote, I can fix it? And failing that, would there be a cheap way to escape all instances of '"' with '\"'?

Comment: generally speaking - it is impossible, you can try to develop your own parsing algorithm which will somehow solve this

Comment: But then does that mean the datastore that the server uses should be taking care of escaping double quotes?

Comment: no, datastore is not responsible for any escaping, server's input/output logic - probably yes

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this at the source. Whatever is generating that JSON is broken and needs to be fixed.